# Geolocation functionality of Xamarin Essentials wrong location results

Tags: xamarin, geolocation

I am using the Geolocation functionality of Xamarin Essentials in my app as a foreground service running all the time and I have noticed on several devices that I sometimes get locations which are really far away from where they should actually be, looking like this (the marked location is far away from the real location):

```
public async Task Run(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () => {
            while (!stopping)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                    var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Best);
                    var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
                    if (location != null)
                    {
                        var message = new LocationMessage
                        {
                            Latitude = location.Latitude,
                            Longitude = location.Longitude
                        };
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            MessagingCenter.Send<LocationMessage>(message, "Location");
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        var errormessage = new LocationErrorMessage();
                        MessagingCenter.Send<LocationErrorMessage>(errormessage, "LocationError");
                    });
                }
            }
            return;
        }, token);
    }
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQvTi.png)

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images.  You need to edit your question to include the code inline, formatted as text

Comment: I don't think this is a software issue - Geolocator is just reporting what it gets from the device GPS

Comment: As Jason said, the Geolocation is used to get GPS info on your device. I set different address in the emulator and everything works fine. Try to check the GPS info is correct in your device.